# How to create inbox notification in ionic

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

I'm still new at ionic. Anyone know how to make something like inbox notification or what it called in ionic 3? Any help will be appreciated, thank you.

Comment: I dont know what inbox notification is but check this: https://ionicframework.com/docs/v3/native/local-notifications/

Comment: I want to save fcm notif in local storage and show it on my apps, I've tried come tutorials but it seems don't working

Answer (score 0):

you can keep notification using ionic storage but in background runnig time some of android devices not store notifications , so you can keep it temp variable then save .

> **Android 6**
>
> https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/reading-local-storage-very-slow-in-background-push-notification-trigger/74869/5